# Organize Imports of entire project using FlashDevelop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

is there any way to Organize Imports of entire project using FlashDevelop? It's an ActionScript project.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

[image]

I understand that you want to do this for your entire project, however unfortunately that option is not possible at this time.

> Re: Organize/Truncate imports for multiple files.
> We don't have short-time plans for that.
>
> - FlashDevelop Admin (Jan 13, 2012).
>
> [`Source`](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=7984)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible in an easy way.

Try creating a Macro (with a shortcurt) using this commands:

```
InvokeMenuItem|RefactorMenu.OrganizeImports
InvokeMenuItem|FileMenu.Save
InvokeMenuItem|FileMenu.Close
```

If you are trying to clear a certain `import`, find it (`Ctrl+1`) and use `F12` to move between results.